# Tensorflow Kotlin/Native could not find 'main' in '<root>' package

Tags: kotlin-native

im want to compile and start.

```
package korat

import tensorflow.TF_Version

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print(TF_Version())
}
```

when im run command:

```
kotlinc-native /home/fnasibov/IdeaProjects/Korat/src/linuxMain/kotlin/korat/Test.kt -l tensorflow
```

it returns an error:

```
error: could not find 'main' in '<root>' package.
```

how can i fix this?

### Update 1

after adding `-e korat.main`
have error

```
error: compilation failed: Provider "jar" not found
    *Source files: Test.kt
    *Compiler version info: Konan: 0.9.3 / Kotlin: 1.3.0
    *Output kind: PROGRAM

exception: java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider "jar" not found
```

Answer (score 5):

Please use `-e korat.main` to specify non-standard entry point.